# Matching relative order in subsequence of fixed length

Tags: algorithms, subsequences, partial-order

I encountered this problem from game development which I will formulate in a more formal way:

> Given a sequence $A = a_1, a_2, \dots, a_m$ and a permutation of $\{1, \dots, n\}$, $B = b_1, b_2, \dots b_n$, find all $i$ such that for all $1 \leq j \leq n$, $a_{i + j}$ is the $b_j$th smallest element of $a_{i + 1}, a_{i + 2}, \dots, a_{i + n}$.

**Example:**

- $A = 6, 1, 3, 4, 5$
- $B = 1, 2, 3$
- $i = 1$: $1, 3, 4$ matches the relative order of $1, 2, 3$
- $i = 2$: $3, 4, 5$ matches the relative order of $1, 2, 3$

The brute force approach consists of sorting each subsequence of length $n$ and comparing the sorted indices to $B$, and this is done $m - n + 1$ times, thus resulting in a time complexity of $\mathcal{O}(mn \log n)$.

I have only managed to improve this very slightly, by sorting only the first subsequence in $\mathcal{O}(n \log n)$ time and then removing $a_i$ and inserting $a_{i + n + 1}$ which both take $\mathcal{O}(n)$ time, resulting in a time complexity of $\mathcal{O}(n \log n + mn)$.

I do realise that my approaches are very rudimentary and there should exist a much more efficient algorithm that runs in less than $\mathcal{O}(m n)$ time. Unfortunately, I cannot think of any relevant algorithms that I know of, and searching online with how I described the problem have yet brought any useful resources.

Comment: "find all $i$ such that for all $1 \leq j \leq n$, $a_{i + j}$ ", do you mean  "find all $i$ such that for all $1 \leq j \leq n-i$, $a_{i + j}$ "? What is that $a_{i + k}$ at the end of the line?

Comment: @Apass.Jack sorry I messed up the indices. Please see the edited version

Comment: Can you imitate Knuth–Morris–Pratt algorithm and write an answer? That approach should be able to produce an efficient algorithm at least in the case when $m$ is much larger than $n$.

Comment: Boyer–Moore string-search algorithm could be imitated as well.

Comment: @Apass.Jack I have thought of kmp since it is an efficient string matching algorithm. However, I do not quite see how I can imitate it in my case where an order is matched. Do you mind giving me a few pointers?

Comment: Suppose $B=1,2,3,4$. If at some index $i$ of $A$, $A[i+1], A[i+2],A[i+3]$ matches $B[1], B[2],B[3]$, but we cannot extend to $A[i+3]$, then we know at next two indices, $i+1$ and $i+2$ of $A$, it cannot match all of $B$ since we know $a[i+2]<a[i+3]$. So we can move from the failing $i$ directly to $i+3$. That is the essence of KMP algorithm.

Comment: If you prefer, I can write an answer. By the way, are you indeed a "12th-grade student" in France? My answer might depend on your background.

Comment: @Apass.Jck I see the gist, but I do appreciate an elaborate answer. And yes, I am indeed in my senior year in a French high school. Thank you for taking such consideration!

Comment: If this problem comes from an online course or contest or article, could you please add a URL in the question. If it comes from a book or a paper, a reference. Before I go ahead, I would like us to pay proper attribute to the original source.

Comment: Hmm, "I encountered this problem from game development". Can you share a bit background about **how this problem appears while in game development**? I am waiting ...

Comment: Sorry for the delay - I was sleeping. The origin of this problem is complex, but it started from a card game in France (https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trou_du_cul_(jeu)) where, to simplify, you must put your cards down in order to win (i.e., you must always put a bigger card). However this order can change, as there can be "revolutions" where the order is reversed. I was wondering with a friend if we could create more "complex orders": instead of just reversing, if you had to follow the order of a certain pattern. To avoid the hassles with actual cards, we coded the game and there's theproblem.

Comment: Also, I do agree that with the KMP algorithm you can avoid some (well, many) unnecessary comparisons, but since we have to generate the indices which change each time we shift the index, don't we still need $O(mn)$ time? Or is there a way to optimise that as well?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85031/discussion-between-apass-jack-and-jingjie-yang).